Fixing the Rotational Origin of a Bone
I'm trying to set up an eye rig, but when it comes to the bones, the eyes don't rotate the way I want to. It's difficult to explain, but it looks like the eyes are rotating in the wrong origin point. I have the bones assigned with a 1.0 weight on all vertices for each eye.
Here's how the bone rotates:
https://imgur.com/a/gsTbQyT
Edit mode is able to give a good demonstration of how I want the eye to rotate. Basically I want to rotate the eye with the origin at its center.
https://imgur.com/a/dd4iVD6
I've tried changing the roll, the object's origin, and moving the bones, but can't find anything that works.

Go to Object Data Properties (green triangle of vertices icon), Vertex groups section, and delete all vertex groups except the correct one.
If the Edit mode rotation is ok, when in edit mode and with all vertices selected, press Shift S > Cursor to Selected, then select the Armature, go to edit mode, select the bone and press Shift S > Selection to Cursor.
If this doesn't solve, please upload the file.
